# Load multiple files from folder without duplicating headers

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have used folder data source in Power BI
the files are excel files with same structure

each one of these files have columns names are first
when I load the data I get the column name as row although i clicked in the 
"Use First row as header" button

how can I remove first row from all files.

I may end with 100s of files in that folder, so I cant remove them one by one

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem to solve. I found answer here:
https://powerbi.tips/2016/08/load-multiple-excel-xlsx-files/

The logic is:

1. When you get data from Excel file, you have column `Date` with value `Table` for each sheet.
2. Refer to `Data` column, **not expanding** it. Add new column:

   `= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "TablesWithHeaders", each Table.PromoteHeaders([Data], [PromoteAllScalars=true]))`
3. Expand column `TablesWithHeaders`.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data:

[image: sample data]

You can apply a text filter on `Column1` to filter out the values.

[image: filter]
[image: filter column 1]

Results:

[image: results]

Assume that you don't have a useful row of data where the value is coincidentally 
 `Column1` for `Column1`.

M query FYR:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Your Previous Steps", each [Column1] <> "Column1")
```

Comment: Hi @asmgx Does this help resolving your question?